# String replace in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have project in Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

```
<a href="{{ route('user', ['url_address' => $user->url_address, 'id' => $user->id]) }}"><img
                                                src="{{ $user->images->first()->path ??  $placeholder }}"
                                                class="img-responsive center" alt="{{ $user->name }}"></a>
```

This return me:

```
<a href="http://name.com/user/name/2"><img src="upload/images/UserImage/c561b1742783ed038521c488d1cd59a1.jpg" class="img-responsive center" alt="angel"></a>
```

I need replace this:

```
upload/images/UserImage/c561b1742783ed038521c488d1cd59a1.jpg
```

to:

```
upload/images/UserImage/thumbs3/c561b1742783ed038521c488d1cd59a1.jpg
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here. You could update your DB data, add a new column to store the thumb path, or modify the existing path in place.

Here's one way to do it using https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-replace-first

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...

$search = 'upload/images/UserImage/';
$replace = 'upload/images/UserImage/thumbs3/';
$original = $user->images->first()->path;

$replaced = Str::replaceFirst($search, $replace, $original );

// Now, use `$replaced` as your image src. 
<a href="{{ route('user', ['url_address' => $user->url_address, 'id' => $user->id]) }}"> 
    <img src="{{ $replaced ??  $placeholder }}"
         class="img-responsive center" alt="{{ $user->name }}">
</a>
```

I should also mention, that in my experience it is easier to maintain a system where all you store in the DB is the file name of the uploaded document. In this case, `c561b1742783ed038521c488d1cd59a1.jpg`.

Your views then control which directory to look in: `...public_path('upload/images/thumbs/' . $user->profile_image)`

Comment: Thank for yours answer. where to add this code: $search = 'upload/images/UserImage/';
$replace = 'upload/images/UserImage/thumbs3/';
$original = $user->images->first()->path;

$replaced = Str::replaceFirst($search, $replace, $original );? to the controller?

Comment: If so, I can not add this to the controller because my code displays a list of users in the blade and I have to dynamically replace these paths...

Comment: In your view. You might not need `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` but I can't verify at the moment.